# My Carousel isn't working....doesn't change, even when I click on the next or previous

Tags: html, css, carousel

Sorry for the size of the links....Stackoverflow doesn't allow link shorteners...
Earlier it was working just fine. But at the time of submission, when I was checking the whole output of the site, I noticed that it wasn't working at all...
It doesn't change on its on..which it use to do earlier...
When I click on the next or the previous button, it just looks as if it was ' href="#" ', it does nothing at all...

Here is the code -
HTML

```
<div class='container'>
<div class='carousel slide' data-ride='carousel' id='myCarousel'>
<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class='carousel-indicators'>
  <li class='active' data-slide-to='0' data-target='#myCarousel'/>
  <li data-slide-to='1' data-target='#myCarousel'/>
  <li data-slide-to='2' data-target='#myCarousel'/>
</ol>

<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class='carousel-inner'>
  <div class='item active'>
    <img alt='Statue of Unity' src='https://southindia1-mediap.svc.ms/transform/thumbnail?provider=spo&inputFormat=jpg&cs=fFNQTw&docid=https://lpuin-my.sharepoint.com:443/_api/v2.0/drives/b!oY30talLiUS8rG_BEWnrXVosZvQbZtBCgL0B34hPVyiHfGeNwOpCTIXwHQY9v522/items/01QPSJLNKSLYWYT7SANNHJ7KMPQETY232Q%3Fversion%3DPublished&access_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJub25lIn0.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.Q0NOVDBRVmVZcW9PanhqdGxiaW4rM3RNY1Y0NzhXLzdyTFJyeG91Sjd5bz0&encodeFailures=1&srcWidth=&srcHeight=&width=1366&height=341&action=Access' style='width:100%;'/>
  </div>

  <div class='item'>
    <img alt='Tea Farms Kerela' src='https://southindia1-mediap.svc.ms/transform/thumbnail?provider=spo&inputFormat=jpg&cs=fFNQTw&docid=https://lpuin-my.sharepoint.com:443/_api/v2.0/drives/b!oY30talLiUS8rG_BEWnrXVosZvQbZtBCgL0B34hPVyiHfGeNwOpCTIXwHQY9v522/items/01QPSJLNNU5JD33JBMEZG2HB4SGJUW4EFW%3Fversion%3DPublished&access_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJub25lIn0.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.Q2tEV3NBb0dWaE01d3UvR0pRS3lyMnZVWXYyUXlxS21sYS9sMzhneVNoVT0&encodeFailures=1&srcWidth=&srcHeight=&width=1366&height=341&action=Access' style='width:100%;'/>
  </div>

  <div class='item'>
    <img alt='Taj Mahal' src='https://southindia1-mediap.svc.ms/transform/thumbnail?provider=spo&inputFormat=jpg&cs=fFNQTw&docid=https://lpuin-my.sharepoint.com:443/_api/v2.0/drives/b!oY30talLiUS8rG_BEWnrXVosZvQbZtBCgL0B34hPVyiHfGeNwOpCTIXwHQY9v522/items/01QPSJLNKX6KUD55J6GRFYUZH2VXE3LZGZ%3Fversion%3DPublished&access_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJub25lIn0.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.VzdGZGUyZFk5SGpkdFZkNzE1SUdCTXZYcFB1RTBSMTRkTEhoMkRoZ1NzVT0&encodeFailures=1&srcWidth=&srcHeight=&width=1366&height=341&action=Access' style='width:100%;'/>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Left and right controls -->
<a class='left carousel-control' data-slide='prev' href='#myCarousel'>
  <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left'/>
  <span class='sr-only'>Previous</span>
</a>
<a class='right carousel-control' data-slide='next' href='#myCarousel'>
  <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right'/>
  <span class='sr-only'>Next</span>
</a>
```

CSS -

```
.carousel{
background: white;
width: 100%;
}
.carousel-item{
text-align: center;
min-height: 360px;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Are you using a JavaScript library to do it? If you do, which one?

Comment: If you want you can get all the code Here -

HTML -
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/b0osS/9fa1a2f9c53e7c1b8c9b040c05565911/raw/79b65fcdf699ea3a4c92a28e773e19f98d0065b1/Index.html

CSS -
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/b0osS/98694f7d3f6422c42d158eeb92da75ad/raw/bff4108afa02157591dea8e0ee62a4dad1ae5a94/projectsem5int219ca1que2style.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a few changes to your code.

The mistakes that were fixed are the following inside of your `carousel-indicators` your `<li>` were first closed incorrectly, therefore, you must change them from

```
<li class='active' data-slide-to='0' data-target='#myCarousel' />
<li data-slide-to='1' data-target='#myCarousel' />
<li data-slide-to='2' data-target='#myCarousel' />
```

to

```
   <li class='active' data-slide-to='0' data-target='#myCarousel'></li>
   <li data-slide-to='1' data-target='#myCarousel'></li>
   <li data-slide-to='2' data-target='#myCarousel'></li>
```

The second mistake I noticed you made was inside `carousel-inner` content
you should use the class `carousel-item` instead of `item`

The third mistake was the class name of the `a` tag is wrong and you didn't close the `span` correctly.

```
<!-- Left and right controls -->
<a class='left carousel-control' data-slide='prev' href='#myCarousel'>
  <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left'/>
  <span class='sr-only'>Previous</span>
</a>
<a class='right carousel-control' data-slide='next' href='#myCarousel'>
  <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right'/>
  <span class='sr-only'>Next</span>
</a>
```

The `a` tag class names should be changed from this

```
  <a class='right carousel-control' data-slide='next' href='#myCarousel'>
  <a class='left carousel-control' data-slide='prev' href='#myCarousel'>
```

to this

```
  <a class='carousel-control-prev' data-slide='prev' href='#myCarousel'>
  <a class='carousel-control-next' data-slide='next' href='#myCarousel'>
```

you didn't close a span probably.

Your span:

```
  <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left'/>
  <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right'/>
```

They should be closed like this

```
 <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left'></span>
  <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right'><span>
```

I also noticed that you were trying to add a custom icon. you can do that by replacing

```
  <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right'><span>
```

by ( the icon bootstrap uses )

```
<span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

or ( custom icon from fontawesome)

```
<span> <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
```

Don't forget to add the `fontawesome CDN` in your `head` if you are going to use the custom icon.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-PgQMlq+nqFLV4ylk1gwUOgm6CtIIXkKwaIHp/PAIWHzig/lKZSEGKEysh0TCVbHJXCLN7WetD8TFecIky75ZfQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

===

### Here is your code after applying all the fixes to it.

```
<div class='container'>
        <div class='carousel slide' data-ride='carousel' id='myCarousel'>
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class='carousel-indicators'>
                <li class='active' data-slide-to='0' data-target='#myCarousel'></li>
                <li data-slide-to='1' data-target='#myCarousel'></li>
                <li data-slide-to='2' data-target='#myCarousel'></li>
            </ol>
            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class='carousel-inner'>
                <div class='carousel-item active'>
                    <img alt='Statue of Unity' src='https://southindia1-mediap.svc.ms/transform/thumbnail?provider=spo&inputFormat=jpg&cs=fFNQTw&docid=https://lpuin-my.sharepoint.com:443/_api/v2.0/drives/b!oY30talLiUS8rG_BEWnrXVosZvQbZtBCgL0B34hPVyiHfGeNwOpCTIXwHQY9v522/items/01QPSJLNKSLYWYT7SANNHJ7KMPQETY232Q%3Fversion%3DPublished&access_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJub25lIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIwMDAwMDAwMy0wMDAwLTBmZjEtY2UwMC0wMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAvbHB1aW4tbXkuc2hhcmVwb2ludC5jb21AZTE0ZTczZWItNTI1MS00Mzg4LThkNjctOGY5ZjJlMmQ1YTQ2IiwiaXNzIjoiMDAwMDAwMDMtMDAwMC0wZmYxLWNlMDAtMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwIiwibmJmIjoiMTU5ODcyNjg0NSIsImV4cCI6IjE1OTg3NDg0NDUiLCJlbmRwb2ludHVybCI6Imp3Y0s0OWpDdnJhNmJGalJLTFhBZmFNWHNpMmlXZzkzZTBESWZ3Yk11bTg9IiwiZW5kcG9pbnR1cmxMZW5ndGgiOiIxMTUiLCJpc2xvb3BiYWNrIjoiVHJ1ZSIsImNpZCI6Ik9EaGtZamMwT1dZdE9EQTVPQzB3TURBd0xUUmhOV1V0WlRFMk5qWTNNMlJoT1RkaSIsInZlciI6Imhhc2hlZHByb29mdG9rZW4iLCJzaXRlaWQiOiJZalZtTkRoa1lURXROR0poT1MwME5EZzVMV0pqWVdNdE5tWmpNVEV4TmpsbFlqVmsiLCJzaWduaW5fc3RhdGUiOiJbXCJrbXNpXCJdIiwibmFtZWlkIjoiMCMuZnxtZW1iZXJzaGlwfGFtaXQuMTE4MTI2MjFAbHB1LmluIiwibmlpIjoibWljcm9zb2Z0LnNoYXJlcG9pbnQiLCJpc3VzZXIiOiJ0cnVlIiwiY2FjaGVrZXkiOiIwaC5mfG1lbWJlcnNoaXB8MTAwMzdmZmVhZTQ5YTAwMkBsaXZlLmNvbSIsInR0IjoiMCIsInVzZVBlcnNpc3RlbnRDb29raWUiOiIzIn0.Q0NOVDBRVmVZcW9PanhqdGxiaW4rM3RNY1Y0NzhXLzdyTFJyeG91Sjd5bz0&encodeFailures=1&srcWidth=&srcHeight=&width=1366&height=341&action=Access'
                        style='width:100%;' />
                </div>
                <div class='carousel-item'>
                    <img alt='Tea Farms Kerela' src='https://southindia1-mediap.svc.ms/transform/thumbnail?provider=spo&inputFormat=jpg&cs=fFNQTw&docid=https://lpuin-my.sharepoint.com:443/_api/v2.0/drives/b!oY30talLiUS8rG_BEWnrXVosZvQbZtBCgL0B34hPVyiHfGeNwOpCTIXwHQY9v522/items/01QPSJLNNU5JD33JBMEZG2HB4SGJUW4EFW%3Fversion%3DPublished&access_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJub25lIn0.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.Q2tEV3NBb0dWaE01d3UvR0pRS3lyMnZVWXYyUXlxS21sYS9sMzhneVNoVT0&encodeFailures=1&srcWidth=&srcHeight=&width=1366&height=341&action=Access'
                        style='width:100%;' />
                </div>

                <div class='carousel-item'>
                    <img alt='Taj Mahal' src='https://southindia1-mediap.svc.ms/transform/thumbnail?provider=spo&inputFormat=jpg&cs=fFNQTw&docid=https://lpuin-my.sharepoint.com:443/_api/v2.0/drives/b!oY30talLiUS8rG_BEWnrXVosZvQbZtBCgL0B34hPVyiHfGeNwOpCTIXwHQY9v522/items/01QPSJLNKX6KUD55J6GRFYUZH2VXE3LZGZ%3Fversion%3DPublished&access_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJub25lIn0.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.VzdGZGUyZFk5SGpkdFZkNzE1SUdCTXZYcFB1RTBSMTRkTEhoMkRoZ1NzVT0&encodeFailures=1&srcWidth=&srcHeight=&width=1366&height=341&action=Access'
                        style='width:100%;' />
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Left and right controls -->
            <a class='carousel-control-prev' data-slide='prev' href='#myCarousel'>
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class='sr-only'>Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class='carousel-control-next' data-slide='next' href='#myCarousel'>
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class='sr-only'>Next</span>
            </a>

        </div>
    </div>
```

and here is a working example I added for you. using bootstrap 4.

```html
<!-- CSS only -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="slider">
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="4"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080 " class="d-block w-100 vh-100" alt="pic-1">
        <div class="overlay "> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1081" class="d-block w-100 vh-100 " alt="pic-2">
        <div class="overlay "> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1082" class="d-block w-100 vh-100 " alt="pic-3">
        <div class="overlay "> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1083" class="d-block w-100 vh-100 " alt="pic-4">
        <div class="overlay "> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1084" class="d-block w-100 vh-100 " alt="pic-5">
        <div class="overlay "> </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: "use this code" is not a helpful answer for future visitors. Describe what was the problem, and why the code you provide solved the issue.

Comment: fair enough I will do so